# Python : I have text file and need to sort by ascending order date-time data

Tags: python-3.x

I have Python code (3.x) like this. The code is read data from the database and write into the text file (file2.text) which date are folder name & last modified date. I need to sort data of last modified date by sort by ascending.

I have tried code about sorting but it doesn't work.

`
My text file is contain this information

```
Foldername:     last modified: 
AR112           2018-06-21 11:42:45 
AR231           2018-07-06 14:25:10 
AR234           2018-06-28 15:10:54 
AR784           2018-07-06 14:25:40 
AR142           2018-04-26 10:35:59 
AR147           2018-06-21 11:56:26 
OTHER           2018-12-10 13:18:21 
*** Last folder created by MC1 at *** :Fri Mar 15 10:41:26 2019
```

and I would like to get this below(date/time sorting by ascending) and write back into text file

```
Foldername:     last modified:
AR142           2018-04-26 10:35:59  
AR112           2018-06-21 11:42:45
AR147           2018-06-21 11:56:26  
AR234           2018-06-28 15:10:54
AR231           2018-07-06 14:25:10  
AR784           2018-07-06 14:25:40 
OTHER           2018-12-10 13:18:21 
*** Last folder created by MC1 at *** :Fri Mar 15 10:41:26 2019`


Here is my code.
```

## --- Test Working

```
#print("Folder is : ",time.ctime(max(os.stat(r).st_mtime for r, d, _ in os.walk(thisdir))))

all_subdirs = (d for d in os.listdir(thisdir) if os.path.isdir(d))
latest_subdir = max(all_subdirs, key=os.path.getmtime, _ )
#latest_subdir = max((os.path.getmtime(f), f) for f in all_subdirs)[1]
print("XXXX=",latest_subdir)
# --- End working
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution: Read in all the lines, sort them by the date, and write them back to a file. In order not to trip over the first and last lines, I handled them seperately, but you could also remove them from the lines before.

```
from datetime import datetime
with open("my_file") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

def sort_key(line):
    if line.startswith("Folder"):
        return 0  # put this at the beginning
    elif line.startswith("***"):
        return float("inf")  # infinity; put this at the end
    date_str = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)[1]
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return date.toordinal()

lines.sort(key=sort_key)
with open("new_file", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Hi L3viathan , Sorry I was mistaken to put my code in the answer box. I deleted it now. Thank you for your help. Let me try to tweak your code in my task.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem by ticking the green checkmark next to it.